# Vega-Lite X-axis labels not showing in full

Tags: vega-lite, vega

In Vega-Lite x-axis label names for bit long, so I have made that to an angle,

the label not showing in full, is it possible to make it visible in full,

also in the tooltip the window not showing full, name going out of window, is it possible to make the window bigger or wrap the text?

Also not all ticks of x-axis showing the label, only alternate ones are showing, how to correct that as well

[image: ![enter image description here]

The full label supposed to be, example:

```
creditloandata-extratreesclassifier-24nov2020-14h45m58s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `labelLimit` axis property; for example ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAHvCAMYBOGYAllCgPYQB2kMAtBgVGdBdiShCxYqAMyoYyrAEwAWRnURSADMtYBGGQAsZAVgC2OgBw4ANCACe8NQF8ThYuUo16TFhHaduXDHwFDR4pKy8ooqSuo62vpGphbwUrb2cKQU1LQMzNDuHFw8Plj8gsJiEtJyCsqqagBsUQbGIGaWcADM1gC6tiB6EGQA1sQoVIwYjSAYjCR01IwA5vBJoCUoYMREZlDmAA6jyfJ6w6hjEARUOAggAgBGGCgAgnMou6wtSmbXtwAyVAdQ8ErWLrNJbiFbESwbba7EAARzQTCgNGgVEQo0BZgA7lQwFBNPAZEoAUA)):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": "creditloandata-extratreesclassifier-24nov2020-14h45m58s", "y": 1},
      {"x": "creditloandata-extratreesclassifier-24nov2020-15h45m58s", "y": 2},
      {"x": "creditloandata-extratreesclassifier-24nov2020-16h45m58s", "y": 3}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "x",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"labelAngle": -30, "labelLimit": 0}
    },
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "width": 400
}
```

[image]

The default `labelLimit` is 100, which means the labels are truncated past 100 pixels. You can set it to a higher value, or set it to zero to indicate that there should be no limit.  See the [Vega-Lite Axis Documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html) for more information.